# Ability to edit a chatter post?

Tags: chatter

Has anyone implemented anything custom in Chatter to allow for the "Edit" of a Chatter post on a feed rather just the standard delete function? Just looking for a quick and efficient way to implement that type of functionality without having to delete an entire post because of a misprint.

Comment: I think this is a really important use case as the Chatter platform matures. I would strongly encourage you to vote on this idea: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kymHAAQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't possible to edit a Chatter post after it has been created. See the [FeedItem](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm) documentation. Update is not a supported call.

Answer (score 3):

From the [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kymHAAQ):

> While the ability to edit chatter posts came in [Summer '15](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_chatter_feeds_edit_posts.htm#rn_chatter_feed_edit_posts), it lacks the ability to edit chatter posts with links or files attached to it.

From the Spring `16 release notes: [Edit Chatter Posts Containing Files or Links](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_chatter_edit_posts_with_files.htm)

> So you wrote an awesome Chatter post and attached an even more awesome picture, but then you forgot to @mention your boss. Previously, you had to use comments to make any changes to Chatter posts that contained files or links. Now you can simply edit the original post. This feature is available in Salesforce Classic and the Napili template in Salesforce Communities.